# Fixing MDT file from Panasonic camcorder

Tags: video-recording, panasonic

When Panaconic videocameras are abruptly interrupted while recording, the video is on the SD card as `.mdt`.

It's supposedly a video stream without a header and a footer.

How can I convert this to be an MP4 which the camera normally produces?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this myself. I had a bad file called: `P1100020.mdt` from my Panasonic LUMIX GX85. The solution is to record a video with the same exact settings, then copy both to a Debian/Ubuntu box under Videos and run:

```
sudo apt install git libavformat-dev libavcodec-dev libavutil-dev
git clone https://github.com/anthwlock/untrunc
cd untrunc
make
sudo cp untrunc /usr/local/bin
cd ~/Videos
untrunc -s  P1100021.MP4 P1100020.mdt
```

Keep in mind that `P1100021.MP4` is my working .mp4 with the same settings. That should spit out a working MP4 for those GNU/Linux users out there with a name like `P1100020.mdt_fixed-s1.MP4`